# Does UAE screen people with HIV/AIDS at the airport?

Tags: hiv-aids, united-arab-emirates

I recently stumbled upon a post [that claims that](http://www.nairaland.com/157507/new-rule-dubai):

> For all the people who wish to come to the UAE for vacation or for shopping there's a new rule. **Upon arrival at the airport an HIV/AIDS test will be administered to all before you are allowed to enter the country.** If you test positive (God forbid!) you will be returned to your country.

I'm well aware that UAE is based on Sharia law, but I find this highly unlikely. Is it true?

Answer (score 6):

Have they had some sort of HIV/AIDS test for some people? **Yes**.

From [HIV/AIDS in the United Arab Emirates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV/AIDS_in_the_United_Arab_Emirates)

> The United Arab Emirates has imposed HIV/AIDS travel restrictions on
>   persons applying for a work or residence visa. An HIV/AIDS test is
>   required for work or residence permits; testing must be performed
>   after arrival.[2]

The citation is to the US Department of State (the link is broken).

This doesn't answer whether tourists are affected.

Comment: Another source: http://www.hivtravel.org/Default.aspx?PageId=143&CountryId=189

Comment: +1, but worth mentioning there is no evidence of tests *at the airport* (and in fact the second source suggests it is not at the airport)

Comment: Many countries don't want HIV+ immigrants.  No surprise here.